# PowerShell - Double loop possible?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, compress-archive

I want to compress a directory in a specific place.
The source path is :  `\\$Computers\Users\$Names`

I want than for each computers a copy of each users directory in the sources path of each computers

I tried to use a `foreach` loop like :

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'PC*'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$Names = Get-aduser -filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty givenname 

Foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Compress-Archive -Path \\$Computer\Users\* -DestinationPath C:\Saves\\$Computer\Test.zip -Force
}
```

This actually work, but I don't know how can I add a second loop inside the loop.

If anyone can just explain me the function or just some advises please for trying to do that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not clear what the inner loop should do or should be for

Comment: I'm sorry my english is not that good ^^, the first loop is for choose a computer from the list $Computers and the second is for choose a name in the list $Names. After that, i want to compress-archive from a specific path for each computer and each usersnames like : \\$Computers\Users\$Names and copy it in an existant folder than have a name like = \\Saves\$Computers\Nameoffolder.zip

Comment: What happens if `\\$Computers\Users\$Names` doesn't exist?

Comment: \\$Computers\Users\$Names exist for few computers and users not all of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're approaching the problem with the wrong logic, you do need an inner loop, however, instead of attempting to compress a user profile that you don't know for sure is there you can instead query the remote computer's **Users** folder to see which ones are there and compress only those ones:

```
$Computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'PC*'").Name
# Add the profiles you want to exclude here:
$toExclude = 'Administrator', 'Public'
$params = @{
    Force = $true
    CompressionLevel = 'Optimal'
}

foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{
    $source = "\\$Computer\Users"
    Get-ChildItem $source -Exclude $toExclude -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        $params.LiteralPath = $_.FullName
        # Name of the zipped file would be "ComputerExample - UserExample.zip"
        $params.DestinationPath = "C:\Saves\$computer - {0}.zip" -f $_.Name
        Compress-Archive @params
    }
}
```

Comment: You get +2 from me;)